# Add one commit before every github release

Tags: javascript, github, npm, version, github-actions

I need to commit some version update changes before each release from github. Is there any github action for that?. I have a npm script `npm run release` to update the version and commit. But i need to run this before each release. I have tried with github release action. But it runs the action only after release. I need to wait the release process until this action completes

Comment: It seems to me you just have to define an event that will trigger before each github release on your repository, and add the commit using it in a workflow. Do you do anything on the repo before generating a new release? (*e.g: a branch or tag creation*)

Comment: The tag creation is happend along with release. And I can use only release event

Comment: If the tag creation is manual, I would suggest to create a workflow using a `workflow_dispatch` event (eventually using inputs if necessary). Then you could perform any operation there before creating the tag along with the release though command line or using an action.